# Undefined offset (in function)

Tags: php

I get this error in my dates function

when my in panel this code calls the function fecha,only when it calls the date it throws the error, the status and the amount, if it appears to me.

```html
<h1>Viendo compra de <span style="color:#08f"><?=$nombre?></span></h1><br>

Fecha: <?=fecha($r['fecha'])?><br>
Monto: <?=number_format($r['monto'])?> <?=$divisa?><br>
Estado: <?=estado($r['estado'])?><br>
```

here is the function

```
<?php


function fecha($fecha){
    $e = explode("-",$fecha);

    $year = $e[0];
    $month = $e[1];
    $e2 = explode(" ",$e[2]);
    $day = $e2[0];
    $time = $e2[1];

    $e3 = explode(":",$time);
    $hour = $e3[0];
    $mins = $e3[1];

    return $day."/".$month."/".$year." ".$hour.":".$mins;

}


?>
```

Comment: Based on your code, `$fecha` is a formatted timestamp; where is it coming from? What is `$r['fecha']`? Because it may be unnecessary to do string parsing like that. For instance it that's a database row, and you're storing actual timestamps (like you should), parsing a string representation back into year, month, etc is nonsense.

Comment: Pls only use relevant tags, do not randomly tag a question with unrelated items from your technology stack.

Answer (score 1):

You need not to reinvent bicycle, just use PHP built in functions:

```
<?php
function fetcha($originalDate) {
    return date("d/m/Y H:i", strtotime($originalDate));
}

echo fetcha('2020-12-06 10:11:12');
```

[Test PHP code here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=137fb8d30de70d9ca062fe08aa2dac0b&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: seems your link is broken ;p